# pyassimp how to create new scene?

Tags: python, assimp

I can load scene from file and export scene,

```
scene = pyassimp.load('test.obj','obj')
pyassimp.export(scene,'test.3ds','3ds')
```

but unable to create new scene for modify.

how to create new empty scene?